# Outputting and saving a csv in PHP

Tags: php, csv, file-handling

I am currently creating and outputting a CSV as follows:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv');
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");

$df = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fprintf($df, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
foreach ($csvLines as $csvLine) {
    fputcsv($df, $csvLine);
}
exit;
```

However, I would like to not only output but also save this file to disk. How can I write `$df` to a file?

**Note** Suggestions on improving my generating the CSV are welcome :)

Comment: `$df = fopen('/path/to/where/you/want/the/file/on/disk.csv', 'w');` instead of opening `php://output`; and then use `readfile('/path/to/where/you/want/the/file/on/disk.csv')` immediately before your `exit` to send it to the browser as well

Comment: Don't write an UTF-8 BOM. It is [not needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) and many times it produces more harm than good.

Comment: @axiac That wisdom unfortunately doesn't hold when trying to make Excel work with CSVs (which is a very common scenario). (Though properly supporting Excel with CSVs is unfortunately even more complex…)

Comment: @MarkBaker Could you put your comment in an answer? It helped me out the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is to write to the file instead of `php://output`, and then send that file directly to the browser using [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv');
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");

$df = fopen('/path/to/where/you/want/the/file/on/disk.csv', 'w');
fprintf($df, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
foreach ($csvLines as $csvLine) {
    fputcsv($df, $csvLine);
}
readfile('/path/to/where/you/want/the/file/on/disk.csv');
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply write to two file pointers:

```
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$file = fopen('somefile.csv');

fprintf($out, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
fprintf($file, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));

foreach ($csvLines as $csvLine) {
    fputcsv($out, $csvLine);
    fputcsv($file, $csvLine);
}

exit;
```